# Удаление элемента из <ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, active-record

Привет! Есть ActiveRecord::Relation следующего вида:

```
2.2.3 :035 > g = Group.sorted.active.limit(100)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Group id: 992, login: "", hashed_password:
"", firstname: "", lastname: "POS-терминалы", admin: false, status: 1, 
last_login_on: nil, language: "", auth_source_id: 1, created_on: "2013-02-20
10:33:36", updated_on: "2013-02-20 10:33:36", type: "Group", identity_url: 
nil, mail_notification: "", salt: nil, must_change_passwd: false, 
passwd_changed_on: nil, otp_secret_key: nil, otp_time: nil, tfa_login: nil,
logout_time: nil>, #<Group id: 1255, login: "", hashed_password: "", 
firstname: "", lastname: "Администраторы СУБД Oracle", admin: false, status:
1, last_login_on: nil, language: "", auth_source_id: 1, created_on: "2013-
11-01 03:52:12", updated_on: "2013-11-01 03:52:12", type: "Group", 
identity_url: nil, mail_notification: "", salt: nil, must_change_passwd:
false, passwd_changed_on: nil, otp_secret_key: nil, otp_time: nil, 
tfa_login: nil, logout_time: nil>,
```

ну и т.д.
Затем у меня есть выборка вида:

```
2.2.3 :036 > Group.all.find(3270)
=> #<Group id: 3270, login: "", hashed_password: "", firstname: "",
lastname: "Отдел анализа и развития бизнес-процессов", admin: false, status:
1, last_login_on: nil, language: "", auth_source_id: nil, created_on: "2016-
07-26 14:03:24", updated_on: "2016-07-26 14:03:24", type: "Group", 
identity_url: nil, mail_notification: "", salt: nil, must_change_passwd:
false, passwd_changed_on: nil, otp_secret_key: nil, otp_time: nil, 
tfa_login: nil, logout_time: nil>
```

Как мне из первой выборки исключить результаты второй? Т.е. мне нужно группу с id 3270 удалить из первой выборки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Rails 4 в языке составителя запросов есть **условия с отрицанием**.

```
Group.sorted.active.where.not(id: 3270).limit(100)
#                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```